# telnetlib capabilities to run remotely shell commands

Tags: python, telnet, remote-access

Is the [telnet library for Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html)  prgramming language able to handle all the shell commands we usually tape on Terminal (UNIX machines, specifically Ubuntu in my case) ?

Asked in an other way: can I execute on a remote Ubuntu server all the commands I am used to run locally, using the [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html) library ? Or does this library handle only a very short list of commands ?

Comment: Use ssh if you want to actually do something useful.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid so telnet can not support commands ?

Comment: See @Serg's answer. Telnet is just a pipe though which you send text. What happens to that text on the other end is not controlled by telnet. There is no "commands" of telnet, its just a connection - you can type any nonsense garbage in it and telnet will happily send it across the connection. Its is not a _remote shell_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python telnet lib as no notion of command : it only allows you to pass strings to the remote host and get the answers.
So you can easily :

- connect to the remote host and get a shell
- interact with this shell with any command you want

In short you can do what you would do over a direct telnet connection.

Simply avoid using full screen applications like vi or emacs, or any ncurses one : it is therorically possible but really tricky ...

Comment: But on this example a command is executed: http://effbot.org/librarybook/telnetlib.htm

Comment: @begueradj You are right, a command is executed in remote host. But telnetlib only sent the string `ls librarybook\n` and it is the shell on the remote host that actually executed the command. If the command used input from stdin, you would provide its input via other lines through telnetlib. As I've allready said you can do with telnetlib what you could do via a direct telnet connexion, neither more nor less.